# Default SDWebImage cache size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdwebimage

Default cache size of SDWebImage. I need both number of files and size of total file it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

If you [search](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=maxCacheSize) through SDWebImage files on github for "maxCacheSize" you'll see that there's no default value. Since it's a @property it won't be initialised with garbage numbers, but will be set to 0. From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html):

> The alloc method has one other important task, which is to clear out
>   the memory allocated for the object’s properties by setting them to
>   zero. This avoids the usual problem of memory containing garbage from
>   whatever was stored before...

So there's no restriction by default judging by the condition in clean up code:

```
if (self.maxCacheSize > 0 && currentCacheSize > self.maxCacheSize) {

//clean up code;

}
```

AFAIK there is no maximum amount of space that your application can use either. You can eat up all of the available space on the device if you wish.